# How to display Visual force page in salesforce one

Tags: community, salesforce1-app

I have added  the Tab to the Navigation Menu through Mobile Navigation.

But I am not able to see my whole page on my mobile screen, not even scroll bar is available. Is their any change in CSS so that whole page will get displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to define a Compact Page Layout for each page in your App. If you don't, you'll get the default Compact Page Layout. See the [Salesforce1 Mobile App Admin Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1appadmin.meta/salesforce1appadmin/) for more on this. If you're using Flex Pages, you'll also want to look at the [Salesforce1 Mobile App Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/).

Generally speaking, only what you define on a Compact Page Layout will appear in the view in a Mobile App. Even then, at most, only the first 4 items will appear when you go to that item until you ask for more. The Default Compact Page Layout typically only provides for 3 items to appear on a page. Again, I refer you to the documentation to learn more.